# Error on if condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a concatenated dataframe. I am iterating over the rows of the dataframes to get the value of that row with a specific if condition as shown below.

```
selected=[]


for index,row in dfs.iterrows():

    if [(row[:,'Panning'][row[:,'Panning']=='Panning']) & (index==0)]:

                selected.append(row[:,'Panning'][row[:,'Panning']=='Panning'].index.tolist())
print selected
```

While I am executing the code I am getting the error on if condition

TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [object] array with a scalar of type [bool]

Comment: Your If statement should not have square brackets around it; make them parentheses.

Comment: I tried using parentheses but did not work.

Comment: should `&` be `and`?

Comment: If i use and I get the following error ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: @depperm- Pandas uses different boolean operators than base python. "The operators are: | for or, & for and, and ~ for not." http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html

Comment: Is dfs a list of dataframes or a singular dataframe? You can't do iterrows() over a list of dataframes.

Comment: @A.Kot dfs is a singular dataframe w

Comment: So then why do you need the condition (index==0)? That will only return the first row.

Comment: I do not want to get the first row...I want to check all rows except the first row. It must be index!=0